# Enterprise Architect displaying information flows in templates

Tags: templates, automation, enterprise-architect

**Background:**
I have a EA package containing a set of about 20 diagrams. I created an EA template that I wanted to use to display all elements and descriptions in the diagram. In these diagrams I have information flow lines going from one element to another. These lines have labels and descriptions. The lines are generated by dragging an arrow from one element to another, selecting information flow, then selecting from an internally defined list of exchange elements.

**Problem:**
When I generate the template none of the information flows appear. I have tried selecting nearly everything that EA will allow me to export in templates and I cannot seem to find where these exist. Here is a copy of my current template.

```
package >
{Pkg.Name}
diagram >
<DiagramName>{Diagram.Name}
{Diagram.DiagramImg}
element >
<ElementName>{Element.Name}
{Element.Notes}
< element
connector >
<ConnectName>{Connector.Name}
{Connector.Notes}
< connector
```

**Note:**
I unfortunately cannot share any of the diagrams due to company policy. Also I am currently exploring using VB to pull the information via scripting

**EDIT:**
I have also tried

```
package>
diagram>
connector>
{connector.Conveyed}
```

This seems to get me some of the information flows but not all. For example one diagram has about 30 information flows and the connector.conveyed field displays only one of the 30 connectors.

Comment: I have no real expertise with EA's document generator, but for the information flows you find a query on EA's forum and I seem to know that you can use queries in templates.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you are looking for **Information Items Conveyed** (it's hard to tell from the description in the question)

You can get it into a template using:

```
package >
diagram >
connector >
{Connector.Conveyed}
< connector
< diagram
< package
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. This was one of the first things I had tried. I thought this would have been what I wanted as well because if I go into the diagram and right-click on the connector>Find items Conveyed, It takes me to the Exchange Element that I am trying to access. However when I put this in my template I seem to get random ones (not all). for example one diagram has about 30 connectors yet I only get 1 connector conveyed. It is one I am looking for however I do not understand why the other 29 dont show up

Comment: There are actually two ways to use conveyed items. One via an information flow connector and another via any other type of connector. The latter creates a hidden information flow connector that actually links to the conveyed items. I can imagine that only one of the two mechanism was implemented in the templates. You might want to report a bug.

Answer (score 0):

I am also having the same issue. I have a port and using Information Flow connectors to connect to 2 ports. I also have more than 1 conveyed items (signals, to be precise).

The only way I was able to get all conveyed items is to use 1 connector for 1 conveyed items. If I convey more than 1 items (Add multiple Information Items conveyed), I also end up getting only 1 out of the list of the conveyed items. It's a random item (in my case, signal).

Comment: You could also get the complete list using an SQL fragment, but that is a bit more complicated.